# insert query while select

Tags: mysql, sql, database

am trying to insert a data via single query.

`select seg_id from seg where product_id='177' and variant_id='527';
insert into main(main_id,main_name,segment_id) values('3333','4444','***')`

I want to replace that *** and place selected seg_id.

Also,main_id,main_name will be taken from user along with product_id and variant_id while segment_id should be fetched from DB.

DB Structure:

Segment table:

`segment_key(PK)
segment_id
product_id
variant_id`

main table:

`main_id
main_name
segment_id
creationdate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into main(main_id, main_name, segment_id)
    select '3333', '4444', seg_id
    from seg
    where product_id = '177' and variant_id = '527';
```